# Explain why this composite function is not allowed?

Tags: functions

Explain why this composite function is not allowed 
when $f(x) = 2x+1, x \in [-5,5]$ 
and $g(x) = x^2, x \in \mathbb{R}, x \geq 0$

How would you change the domains so that the function $fg(x)$ can exist?

Comment: The range of $g$ is not the same as the domain of $f$. Define $f$ only on $[0,5]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $g$ is not the same as the domain of $f$. So you're making $f$ take in values from $g$ that it's not allowed to take. Restrict the domain of $g$ to $[-\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{5}]$. Then the range of $g(x)$ is $[0,5]$ which is a subset of the domain of $f$. So $f$ can most definitely take in those values. Then $fg(x)$ is most definitely defined.

In general if you have a composite function $fg(x)$ for arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$. Then for the composition to be "allowed" we must have the range of $g$ be a subset of the domain of $f$.

Comment: That makes the range of $g$ $[0,5]$, bu tthat doesn't matter, at least it is $\subseteq $ the domain of $f$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Woopsies, that was a brain fart on my part. Thanks a ton!